# sum of elements of an irreducible representation of a group

Tags: group-theory

Show that the sum over a group of the matrix elements of any irreducible representation other than the identity representation is equal to zero.

This is the exercise in a group theory textbook, the question is the exactly as the book presents. Thanks for help.

Comment: You really ought to mention the name of the book, I searched around and found the book in question and its "Applications of group theory in quantum mechanics" by Petrashen & Trifonov page 47, exercise 3.7

Answer (score 2):

For all $h$ in $G$, $$\sum_{g{\rm\ in\ }G}\rho(g)=\sum_{g{\rm\ in\ }G}\rho(gh)=\sum_{g{\rm\ in\ }G}\rho(g)\rho(h)=\left(\sum_{g{\rm\ in\ }G}\rho(g)\right)\rho(h)$$ so it reduces to showing that $I-\rho(h)$ is invertible for some $h$ in $G$.

Comment: Thanks. But if for all h in G, $I-\rho(h)$ is not invertible, how to deduce a contradiction?

Comment: Perhaps easier to note that this calculation shows that the given sum spans a subrepresentation on which the group acts trivially.

Comment: @Tobias, Oh, I see! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Hi, I was wondering if you could perhaps elaborate on the last line (sentence) in your proof? Namely, how does "so it reduces to showing that $I−\rho(h)$ is invertible for some $h \in G$" show that the sum is zero?

Comment: $A=AB$ can be rewritten as $A(I-B)=0$. If $I-B$ is invertible, then you can multiply both sides of that equation on the right by $(I-B)^{-1}$ to get $A=0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks but why $A=AB$? $B=\rho(h)$? But, what is $\rho$ in the first place, is it some notation for an IRREP like $D(g)$?

Comment: If your question is about what the notation stands for, you could have saved us both some trouble by just saying that you didn't know what was meant by $\rho(h)$. The question is about "the sum over a group of the matrix elements of any irreducible representation", so, yes, $\rho$ is an irreducible representation. It's the notation I'm familiar with – I don't know what your $D(g)$ notation means.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Okay, you're right, I should have said that to start with, you were taught ring theory and module theory I'm guessing, so you use the notation that mathematicians use, I was never taught ring theory, I use the notation, $D(g)$ that most physicists use. So $h$ is the element corresponding to the trivial IRREP? And, are you are really saying that $A=\rho(g)=AB=\rho(g)\rho(h)$? I don't get this at all sorry, simple to you, but not easy for me to see. Thanks Gerry

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, $D(g)$ is an irreducible representation.

Comment: I don't know what it means for an element of the group to correspond to the trivial representation. We have $$\sum_{g\in G}\rho(g)=\left(\sum_{g\in G}\rho(g)\right)\rho(h)$$ so just line that up with $A=AB$ to see what $A$ is and what $B$ is.