# Selection rules: Why is $\frac1m\sum_g\sum_{\lambda}^{\oplus} \underline{\underline{I}}_{\,\lambda}\otimes\underline{\underline{D}}^{(\lambda)}(g)=0$?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, representation-theory, direct-sum, direct-product

Here is the derivation from some notes given to me. I uploaded these handwritten notes for 2 reasons:

1. To show you that this is the only source of information I have available to me (and it's incredibly difficult to learn from it).
2. In the hopes that you can make more sense of them than I can.

There are two expressions in these notes for which I would like to understand, which I have marked with red question marks above the relevant expressions.

[image: Selection rules derivation part 1]

[image: Selection rules derivation part 2]

For the first expression,

$$\frac1m\sum_g\underline{\underline{D}}^{(\lambda)}(g)=\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{for rest of $\lambda$'s} \\
1, & \text{$\lambda$ for fully symmetric IRREP}
\end{cases}$$
The $\underline{\underline{D}}^{(\lambda)}(g)$ in this expression (I think) is supposed to represent the triple direct product at the top of the page, namely,
$$\underline{\underline{D}}^{(\lambda)}(g)\equiv\Big[{\underline{\underline{D}}^{(1)}}^*\otimes {\underline{\underline{D}}}^{\prime} \otimes {\underline{\underline{D}}^{(2)}}\Big]_{n,\,\beta,\,p,\, i,\,\alpha,\,j}$$
This $\frac1m\sum_g\underline{\underline{D}}^{(\lambda)}(g)$ as I understand it is not an orthogonality expression (but it should be), else how can it possibly be equal to zero or $1$?

---

While in the middle of constructing this question I was able to find a PDF version of a book$^{\large\zeta}$ that has a specific chapter that derives selection rules in a remarkably similar way to the notes I have above:
[image: Selection rules second page]

I would like to know why "We note that the sum of matrices of any irreducible representation, other than the identity representation, over the group, is equal to the zero matrix (see Exercise 3.7)". Which is written in the paragraph underneath equation $(21.7)$ above. This exercise 3.7 has been asked about and answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2788522/sum-of-elements-of-an-irreducible-representation-of-a-group) which I found earlier and put a comment below the question to indicate the source. User @[Gerry Myerson](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8269/gerry-myerson) answered that question, but I am unable to understand his proof.

So in summary, I would like to know why $\sum_g\sum_{\lambda}^{\oplus} \underline{\underline{D}}^{(\lambda)}(g)=0?$

Or, if you prefer, could someone please prove why the sum over a group of the matrix elements of any irreducible representation other than the identity/fully symmetric/trivial representation is equal to zero?

---

### Update:

Although this update possibly should be asked as a separate question and if I am told to do this then I will comply, the reason I ask it here is that it is simply regarding applications of the expression given in the title to this post. I have a few small questions regarding the final page of the authors' written lecture notes (page 74), embedded as an image:

[image: Selection rules page 3 modified]

As ever, I have scribbled red question marks over the parts I don't understand.

I know that for a direct product of two matrices, say $\underline{\underline{A}}=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}& a_{12}\\a_{21}& a_{22}\\ \end{pmatrix} \,\, \text{and} \,\,\,\underline{\underline{B}}=\begin{pmatrix}b_{11}& b_{12} & b_{13}\\b_{21}& b_{22}& b_{23}\\b_{31}& b_{32}& b_{33} \end{pmatrix}\implies\underline{\underline{A}}\otimes \underline{\underline{B}}=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}\,\underline{\underline{B}}& a_{12}\,\underline{\underline{B}}\\a_{21}\,\underline{\underline{B}}& a_{22}\,\underline{\underline{B}}\\ \end{pmatrix}$

But that was the direct product for matrices, how does this direct product work for characters?

So looking at the character table for $C_{3v}$ the author of these notes written that for $z$- polarised light $\langle\psi_{A_1}|\hat z | \psi_E\rangle$ for which the decomposition, ${\color{red}{\chi_{A_1}\otimes\chi_{A_1}}}\otimes\chi_E=\chi_E\ne\chi_{A_1}$. Although I know that for a transition to be allowed, its matrix element must be non-zero, as shown to me in the proofs by @[Gerry Myerson](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8269/gerry-myerson) and @[lEm](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/319071/lem). Therefore, to be non-zero the decomposition must contain the trivial representation, which in this case (from the $C_{3v}$ character table) is the IRREP $A_1$, but why is $\chi_{A_1}\otimes\chi_{A_1}\otimes\chi_E=\chi_E$? Is the red part equal to 1? I know this information is coming from the character table somehow, but I don't understand how.

The author then determines whether the matrix element,  $\langle\psi_{A_1}|\hat x | \psi_E\rangle$ for the same transition ($A_1 \to E$) for $x$-polarised light is non-zero by the decomposition, $\chi_{A_1}\otimes\chi_{E}\otimes\chi_E=\chi_E=(4,1,0)$. But, where does this $(4,1,0)$ come from and *how* does this 'contain $A_1$'? I looked at the $C_{3v}$ character table and naively note that summing together the totals for the 3 columns gives $(4,1,0)$, but this could just be a coincidence.

I won't ask about the last 2 red question marks for now, since I may be able to answer them once I've understood the first two.

---

### Edit:

@lEm Okay, I think I see it now, the $(4,1,0)$ is the whole row of $E$ multiplied by itself, not sure why though. Need to think more, any hints please anyone?

---

$^{\large\zeta}$The textbook page 265 embedded in this post as an image is from "Applications of group theory in quantum mechanics" by Petrashen & Trifonov.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an elaboration of Gerry Myerson's answer in the post that you have linked. In any group $G$, multiplication by any element $g\mapsto hg$ would give you a bijection from $G$ to itself, so summing over $g$ is the same as summing over $hg$, therefore $$S=\sum_{g\in G}\rho(g)=\sum_{g\in G}\rho(hg)$$
But $\rho(hg)=\rho(h)\rho(g)$ by property of representation, and so $\rho(h)S=S$ for any $h\in G$. Now if you look at the column vectors $S_i$ of $S$. The above implies that $\rho(h)S_i=S_i$ for all $h\in G$. So the span of $S_i$ gives you a subrepresentation, so by irreducibility this is either the whole vector space or the trivial zero vector space $\{0\}.$ This cannot be the whole representation because that would imply $\rho(h)=I$ for all $h\in G$ which is not irreducible. Finally this implies that span of $S_i$ is $\{0\}$. So $S=0$.

*Edit*: For the follow-up question

The notation $\chi=\chi_{A_1}\otimes\chi_E\otimes\chi_E=(4,1,0)$ just means that $\chi(E)=\chi_{A_1}(E)\chi_E(E)\chi_E(E)=4$, $\chi(C_3)=1$ and so on. It signifies the value of $\chi$ on the conjugacy classes. Now by property of irreducible characters, every character (in fact class function) $\chi$ can be written as a linear combination of the irreducible ones. In our case, we have $$\chi=(4,1,0)=(1,1,1)+(1,1,-1)+(2,-1,0)=\chi_{A_1}+\chi_{A_2}+\chi_E$$

In general, you can find out the coefficients by taking inner product $\langle \chi, \chi_{A_1}\rangle$ and so on.

Comment: By the way, just a suggestion: your question is purely a mathematical one so it was unnecessary to put in all the physics backgrounds and context. The readers can get to the point of your main question quicker if you ask more concisely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have added an answer myself regarding an application of your proof. Would you mind taking a look at this?

Comment: I've just realized something- in the original exercise statement: "Show that the sum over a group of the matrix elements of any irreducible representation other than the identity representation is equal to zero." The problem is, I started with *reducible* representation of $C_{4v}$, and tried to reduce it into an irreducible form (the 2d and 1d 'set of matrices'). But this was never allowed, as the statement only works when starting with an irreducible representation right from the beginning, is that it?  Now this is why I couldn't get the sum of $a_{33}$ matrix elements to equal zero.

Comment: Well as I've said, the statement works for irreducible representation. So the sum won't be zero if you start with a reducible one. But you can still look at its irreducible factor (the 2 by 2 matrices that you identified), this is a subrepresentation that is now irreducible, and hence the proposition applies.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought originally; the 2 by 2 matrices in the first block are an irreducible factor, so the proposition applies. But what concerns me here is that the last block is also an irreducible factor, the 1 by 1 matrices - $a_{33}$ matrix elements, but these do *not* sum to give zero, they actually sum to give 8 (as I shown in my 'answer'). This is simply the only part of this question that remains a mystery to me; do you know why the proposition applies to the 2 by 2 matrices (sums to zero) but not the 1 by 1 matrices ($a_{33}$)?

Comment: Read your proposition again, it says "other than the identity representation". The one dimensional subrepresentation is precisely the identity representation, since $a_{33}(g)=1$ for any $g$.

Comment: Ah, so that is what is meant by the 'identity representation'; is this general for 3 by 3 matrices, and the $a_{33}$ matrix elements together give the identity rep? Now I see why I was getting $8$ before instead of $1$ (as I didn't divide by order of group $|G|=8=m$). If you'll forgive me this has lead to a few small further questions (question updated), if you refuse to answer these then I understand (one such user actually did this already in an earlier question of mine, as I do get quite annoying with many questions), you have already been so helpful, I appreciate that.

Comment: Identity representation just means that $\rho(g)=\operatorname{Id_V}$ for any $g\in G$. For your new question, first of all it is better to open a new question to ask instead of continuing in your original post. But to answer your question, the $\otimes$ for matrices is not called the direct product, but called the Kronecker product. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product
In the wikipedia page, you can see that it satisfies property $\operatorname{tr}(A\otimes B)=\operatorname{tr}(A)\operatorname{tr}(B)$. So on the level of character, this means $\chi_{V\otimes W}=\chi_V\chi_W$.

Comment: Let's continue the discussion in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130291/discussion-room-for-blazes-question

Comment: Yes, this $\operatorname{tr}(A\otimes B)=\operatorname{tr}(A)\operatorname{tr}(B)$ is something I already knew, but I still don't see why
 $\chi_{A_1}\otimes\chi_{E}\otimes\chi_E=\chi_E=(4,1,0)$. I wrote message in the chat you linked me to also.

Comment: Congratulations on the bounty, thank you for all your help, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you. And good luck to your future studies. Again, I would like to suggest politely that you ask more concisely in your future questions. It would help you get more on point answers.

Comment: Understood, I'll try to do that in future, thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* an answer but is too long for a comment, given @lEm's answer above, the proof I actually understand, but it is the interpretation that is confusing me here. So the original problem statement was to:

> Show that the sum over a group of the matrix elements of any irreducible representation other than the identity representation is equal to zero.

which can be found on page 47, exercise 3.7, "Applications of group theory in quantum mechanics" by Petrashen & Trifonov:

[image: exercise 3.7]

I have highlighted exercise 3.7 to show where it comes from in the context of other questions on that page.

I am now looking for an example (or application) of the proof given in the other answer by @lEm. So I choose as my example the $C_{4v}$ point group which can be found in my earlier [question on constructing the character table for $C_{4v}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4245538/how-to-construct-the-c-4v-character-table-given-its-cayley-table).

But just for brevity, I will restate the **block-diagonal** matrices for the group elements here:

$C_4=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},\,C_4^3=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},\,C_2=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},$

$\sigma_x=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},\,\sigma_y=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},\,\sigma_d=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},\,\sigma_{d^\prime}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

and
$E=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

So in order to "Show that the sum over a group of the matrix elements of any irreducible representation other than the identity representation is equal to zero",  I note that all matrix elements $a_{11},\, a_{12},\, a_{13}, \cdots a_{32}$ of $C_{4v}$ apart from $a_{33}$ *all* sum to zero,
$\begin{bmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & \color{red}{a_{33}}
\end{bmatrix}$

As an example, just to make clear what I am doing; I am taking a particular matrix element and then summing the same entry in each of the 8 matrices that make up the representation for $C_{4v}$. So, taking say $a_{21}$ for example, for each matrix of elements: $C_4(a_{21})+ C_4^3 (a_{21})+C_2(a_{21})+\sigma_x(a_{21})+\sigma_y(a_{21})+\sigma_d(a_{21})+\sigma_d^\prime (a_{21})+E(a_{21})=1+-1+0+0+0+1+-1+0=0$ and this works for all matrix elements except the $a_{33}$'s, which sum up to give 8.

---

My question is; why does this sum give 8 (for the $a_{33}$'s) instead of zero?

---

### Update:

Just for reference, I want to show why the first 2 of the red question marks (shown below) are allowed/forbidden using the information taught to me in the updated answer by @lEm:

[image: Selection rules page 3]

$\color{red}{1}$: For $\langle\psi_{A_1}|\hat z | \psi_E\rangle$
$$\chi(E)=\chi_{A_1}(E)\chi_{A_1}(E)\chi_E(E)=1\times 1 \times 2=2$$
$$\chi(2C_3)=\chi_{A_1}(2C_3)\chi_{A_1}(2C_3)\chi_E(2C_3)=1\times 1 \times 1=-1$$
$$\chi(3\sigma_v)=\chi_{A_1}(3\sigma_v)\chi_{A_1}(3\sigma_v)\chi_E(3\sigma_v)=1\times 1 \times 0=0$$
So for $z$ polarised light, for transistion $A_1 \to E$:  $\chi_{A_1}\otimes\chi_{A_1}\otimes\chi_E=(2,-1,0)=\chi_{E}\ne \chi_{A_1}\implies$ forbidden, (zero as does not contain indentity representation, $\chi_{A_1}$).

$\color{red}{2}$: For $\langle\psi_{A_1}|\hat x | \psi_E\rangle$
$$\chi(E)=\chi_{A_1}(E)\chi_{E}(E)\chi_E(E)=1\times 2 \times 2=4$$
$$\chi(2C_3)=\chi_{A_1}(2C_3)\chi_{E}(2C_3)\chi_E(2C_3)=1\times -1 \times -1=1$$
$$\chi(3\sigma_v)=\chi_{A_1}(3\sigma_v)\chi_{E}(3\sigma_v)\chi_E(3\sigma_v)=1\times 0 \times 0=0$$
So for $x$ polarised light, for transistion $A_1\to E$:  $\chi_{A_1}\otimes\chi_{E}\otimes\chi_E=(4,1,0)=\chi_{A_1}+\chi_{A_2}+\chi_{E}\implies$ allowed, as contains $\chi_{A_1}$ (non zero as contains identity representation $\chi_{A_1}$).

Comment: This is not irreducible for three reasons. (1) It contradicts the proposition in question: the sum of matrices does not give you the zero matrix. (2) In the question linked, look at the character table, the value $\chi(e)=\operatorname{tr}(I)=\dim V$ is the dimension of irreducible representations. Therefore it is impossible to have 3 dimensional irreducible representations.

Comment: (3) It is reducible precisely because it can be written as block diagonal matrices simultaneously (in some basis). This means that there are subspaces $\operatorname{span}{e_1,e_2}$ and $\operatorname{span}{e_3}$ that are subrepresentations. The one dimensional subrepresentation is the identity representation $\rho(g)=1$ for all $g$. And the two dimensional subrepresentation is irreducible.

Comment: @lEm I thought we were summing together matrix *elements* not just matrices, which is what you wrote in your first comment. Is a zero matrix not the same as a numerical zero? Okay, so applying what you said, since all 8 matrices are reducible then if I reduce them all to a 2-dimensional matrix and a 1 dimensional, then these are irreducible. So this means I can sum over all matrix elements of a representation like how I did in my answer above, or are you saying that......

Comment: @lEm  ..... this logic: $C_4(a_{21})+ C_4^3 (a_{21})+C_2(a_{21})+\sigma_x(a_{21})+\sigma_y(a_{21})+\sigma_d(a_{21})+\sigma_d^\prime (a_{21})+E(a_{21})=1+-1+0+0+0+1+-1+0=0
$ is invalid? If so why, because $a_{21}$ is from the 2 dimensional irreducible block and for, say the identity element, this is $E=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0  \\
0 & 1  \\
\end{bmatrix}$ this element is $0$ for example, summing over the same matrix element in the other 7 matrices will give $\{0\}$, so what's the problem?

Comment: There are several things here: (1) As you noted, if you sum over $a_{33}$ entry, then you don't get $0$. If you get the sum of all matrix is zero, that means sums of all the corresponding entries are zero. I am only saying that your example of representation is reducible and hence the proposition does not apply. As you noted the sum of matrices has zero entries everywhere except $a_{33}$. (2) I am talking about the representation being irreducible, not the matrices. You should read some books that cover the basics of what these mean.

Comment: @lEm Yes, well done, I should have known I was confusing something, thanks for mentioning that (2), as that was helpful. Since my example failed for reasons you mentioned, would you mind just giving one simple example of an irreducible representation whereby the matrix elements for each matrix of the representation sum to give zero, if possible please do this without using character tables?

Comment: How about this 2 dimensional irreducible representation of the quaternion group $Q_8$? You can verify the sum is indeed the zero matrix.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group#Matrix_representations

Comment: @lEm Thanks for the example. There's just one more thing I would like to know: when you said, "I am talking about the representation being irreducible, not the matrices". But the representation for $C_{4v}$ *is* the set of 8 matrices shown above, right? If so, then is writing all the 8 matrices as a sum of 1d and 2d matrices (like I did for $E$) not the same as making the representation ($C_{4v}$) itself irreducible? I feel like there is a subtlety I am still missing.

Comment: I was merely correcting your use of terminology. It may be a bit pedantic but we usually don't call a matrix reducible. When we say a representation is reducible, it means that there are subspace $W\subset V$ so that all $\rho(g)$ preserves. In your example, it is particularly nice because you can find out the subspaces directly. Actually this is even nicer because it is *decomposable*. The reason why I corrected the terminology is that a representation doesn't have to be in terms of matrices, sometimes we would look at representation on abstract vector spaces $V$ without a natural basis.

Comment: Also it is not completely precise to say a representation is the same as some set of matrices. Because you have to respect the compatibility of composition of elements.

Comment: @lEm Okay, thanks for answer and explanation, 'representation=set of matrices', was the definition of representation I was given as can be seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4258598/question-regarding-notation-and-meaning-of-representations-in-representation-t?noredirect=1&lq=1), though this group theory course was taught from a physics department and it looks like they don't teach it as rigorously as you have been taught it.

Comment: It is not wrong, just a bit imprecise. If having matrices in mind helps with your intuition, then it is not necessarily a bad idea as well. I think for you right now, it is beneficial to work through some examples and compare them with abstract properties of representations that you find in textbooks.

Comment: @lEm Hi there, I have used what you taught me in your updated answer to check my understanding by computing the matrix elements for the first 2 red question marks in my now updated question and 'answer'. Could you please take a moment to confirm whether my demonstration is correct? Many thanks.

Comment: I cannot comment on the physics but the calculations of the characters are correct.